# Implement merge method in ruby

Tags: ruby, merge, hashmap, array-merge

I'm trying to implement merge method in my code.

```
A = { "a" => 200, "b" => 100 }
B = { "b" => 100, "c" => 300 }
```

So when I call `A.merge_method(B)` in my main function, it should return

```
A.merge_method(B) #=> {"a"=>200, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}
```

How can I implement without using merge method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the general idea: collect all the keys of any hashes to be merged, then for each of the keys, collect the values in all the hashes that have that key, and sum them.

```
module HashWithMergeReduce
  refine Hash do
    def merge_reduce(*others, &op)
      hashes = [self, *others]
      hash_keys = hashes.map(&:keys).inject(Set.new, &:+)
      hash_keys.each do |key|
        hashes_with_key = hashes.select { |hash| hash.has_key?(key) }
        self[key] = hashes_with_key.map { |hash| hash[key] }.reduce(&op)
      end
      self
    end
  end
end

module TestHashWithMergeReduce
  using HashWithMergeReduce
  a = { "a" => 200, "b" => 100 }
  b = { "b" => 100, "c" => 300 }  
  puts a.merge_reduce(b, &:+)
  # => {"a"=>200, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}
end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: <module:TestHashWithMergeReduce>': uninitialized constant TestHashWithMergeReduce::HashWithMergeReduce (Name Error)

Comment: That's very strange, it's defined right above it. (If you execute it in Irb, it should just work; if you execute it in a file, you'll need `require 'set'`; but the only way I can see you getting the error you got is if you only executed the bottom half of my code.) Obviously you could write it without a refinement, too.

Answer (score 2):

I can't bring myself to add the method `merge_method` to the class `Hash`, not only because it contaminates a core class, but also because it's only applicable to a small subset of hashes, ones for which all values are numeric.

One could `refine` `Hash`, as @Amadan has done, but I think it makes more sense to simply create a method similar to module methods that behave as functions (e.g, `Math::sqrt`), that takes all hashes as arguments.

```
def sum_values_by_key(*hashes)
  hashes.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| g.each { |k,v| h[k] += v } }
end
```

```
sum_values_by_key({ "a" => 200, "b" => 100 }, { "b" => 100, "c" => 300 })
  #=> {"a"=>200, "b"=>200, "c"=>300}

sum_values_by_key({ "a" => 200, "b" => 100 }, { "b" => 100, "c" => 300 },
                  { "a" => 150, "c" => 250 }) 
  #=> {"a"=>350, "b"=>200, "c"=>550}
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) that defines a default value, which here is zero. The expression:

```
h[k] += v
```

expands to:

```
h[k] = h[k] + v
```

If this hash has been defined `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` has a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality is evaluated to return the value of `k`. If, however, `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right returns the default value, zero, to become:

```
h[k] = 0 + v
```

I've also changed the method name to make it more meaningful.